# error with vim errorformat using make project invoking multiple compilers

Tags: vim, makefile, mono

I have a make project creating binaries using various back-ends…
→ C, C++, csharp, java… on linux using *mono* csharp compiler, gcc, etc…

1. if I choose a single back-end (example csharp) by open a XXX.cs file than the make-output-error parser working OK… this mean error-output is parsed proper and I can jump to the error right away…
2. if I choose the toplevel make… (open vim without file on a toplevel directory) than the make-output-error parser does **not** work properly.

I discovered that the **vim** *errorformat* variable has changed between 1. and 2.

and now my question: how I can tell vim to recognize the *error-output* from C,C++,CSharp… and Java during run of the toplevel make ?

Answer (score 0):

Whatever filetype plugin you have for C# is probably changing the value of `:help 'errorformat'` to work with C# compilers while you are left with the default value when running your top level `make` which, I assume, outputs errors as-is, without any filtering.

In order for Vim to interpret correctly the potentially mixed output of all your compilers you could:

- set `errorformat` to a value that would work with all those formats,
- or add a step to your build process that unifies every native output format into a single format that Vim can interpret without effort.

First option, find the `errorformat` values used by every compiler and prepend them to the default value at startup:

```
set errorformat^=<efm for c#>
set errorformat^=<efm for cpp>
...
```

Second option, I've been thinking for many years about writing a program that would do just that but never found the time to even write a `README.md`. If such a thing doesn't exist you will have to `sed` and `awk` your way on your own I'm afraid.

Comment: a filter would be fine… because a filter can be used everywhere… this mean every build process… make or a single compiler… is filter through this **error-filer** and the output would be normalized.